# "type": "module" import issue

Tags: javascript, import, module, requirejs

Using js librairies, I struggle with the fact that require and import are not suitable together. When I write "type": "module" in the package.json, then import works but require doesn't, and when I don't, the opposite happens. I don't get how to import both of the two librairies.

I import fs like this :

```
const fs = require('fs')
```

and in the other file I am importing PythonShell like this :

```
import { PythonShell } from 'python-shell'
```

Is there a way to have "type" : "module" only applying for one librairy in my package.json ? Or can I import one like the other in order to use only one key word (import or require) ?

Thank you,
have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to use import to use the `PythonShell` class from python-shell, you can just use `require()` so your code would look like this

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const PythonShell = require('python-shell').PythonShell;

// ...
```